# Should spammy comments be flagged or not?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Why would a flag of this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264020/fastest-possible-xml-handling-in-delphi-for-very-large-documents#comment57961243_264020),

> If delphi is not the only platform to consider, vtd-xml is hands-down
>   best at large documents! – [vtd-xml-author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129732/vtd-xml-author) Jan 31 at 22:29

on this question,

[Fastest possible XML handling in Delphi for very large documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264020/fastest-possible-xml-handling-in-delphi-for-very-large-documents)

be ***declined***?

1. OP is clearly asking about **Delphi**, where vtd-xml doesn't run.
2. The comment is an **unsolicited**, **unsubstantiated**, and **off-topic** advertisement for the commenter's product.

For the record, here is my "other" flag comment:

> Self-serving, unsubstantiated claim touting commenter's own product
>   should be removed and sold instead as a (preferably paid)
>   advertisement.

I'm a gold badge holder in XML and am tired of seeing this character using SO to tout his product.  In fact, there are not [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211192/290085) but [*two*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420239/290085) **deleted answers** 7 years prior to the flagged comment on this very same question where he also tried to spam his product.

Other flags I've raised for this sort of problem have been accepted.  What's changed?  Are these sorts of comments now welcome?

Comment: I believe it all goes to *who* reviews your flags!! :)

Comment: Sure, go ahead and flag the comment...as "Other."..and be **specific**. On the other hand, he's obviously upfront that he wrote the software...so it's not *exactly* spam. Unhelpful maybe...though.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Disclosure is a requirement to discuss one's product, not a license to peddle it.  Also, did flag, and did comment specifically -- you may have missed that part of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: How come it's not the first time I see this [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=vtd-xml-author&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search), not saying users is spamming but maybe time to notify about "overt self-promotion" see [behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: FWIW, I had to read your comment a couple times before I fully understood it. Keeping it simple might work better, e.g. *"This comment is an advertisement for the commenter's product. It should be removed. btw, this is not the first time this commenter has done this."*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That was me, and I apologize, I think I fat-fingered that one. I was reviewing other posts by that user and had deleted others but somehow declined that comment flag. I've deleted that comment.

You're right, that was excessively self-promotional and should have been deleted. I and other moderators have removed other posts of theirs that we felt were over the line. We have had a conversation with them about this.

Sorry about that, I don't know how that happened.

Comment: Is there a badge for being classy? Certainly should get one for this, it is nice that moderators add transparency to decisions like you often do on meta, and I wish others would be as attentive about it.

Comment: Thanks, Brad.  You might let perpetual offenders know that beyond any punitive actions SO might take, there are readers (some fairly influential) who will not be able to recommend a product from a company so lacking in decorum.

Comment: Occasional correctable mistakes in moderation are a small price to pay for the great job our mods do at stopping regular uses like myself from even seeing most of the flood of really bad stuff.  They must have to click through a lot of stuff quickly to keep up with it, but that's fine because they're always ready to correct mistakes when we notice them.  Even better, with a gracious apology.

Comment: Lately it seems like you're the naught mod always answering to the head master at school on meta ;)

Comment: @Yvette Yeah, I can't count how many times I heard from (non SO member) developers that "all the solutions are over there", "everything is so high quality", "they couldn't work without it"... They don't know the amount of work the community and the moderators put in to filter out trash to reach this goal.

Comment: @totymedli yes agree and mods are people and also volunteers.